# retrieve data from a related table in a loop that is recovering other data from another table

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new with cakephp .. sorry, if my question seems basic..
I have models: user, post, comment, all related and need to show
comments on the post view .... but also want to show the username and I can't access this field of the user model. 
I have user_id and post_id in comment.php model and user_id in post.php model, but inside the loop how can i access the username field of the user model??

I have this on ... posts / view.ctp

```
    <?php foreach ($post['Comment'] as $comment): ?>            
    <tr<?php echo $class;?>>

    // this does not work
    // echo $comment['user_id']['username'];

    <td><?php echo $comment['user_id']; ?>   
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $comment['created'];?></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $comment['content'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

then how could I fix it?? thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem .... the most common way of trial and error ..
how to fix it was ..

```
  $this->Post->recursive = 2; //in posts_controller.php
```

and then ...

```
 <?php foreach ($post['Comment'] as $comment): ?>            
 <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
 <!-- this is the way to access -->
 <td><?php echo $comment['User']['username']; ?></td>
 .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set auth in your any of you controller.If not,add it in your controllers and try using
`$this->Auth->user('username');` which will give you current user username any where in you controller.You can use this in your view like this

> $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')

//returns particular field value
by this you can get everything from you User table in any acontroller
Find out more about Aut component **[here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1250/Authentication)**

I can make my answer better if you can post how you coded your controller....and pass exact errors that your peroject interrupts..